Grub menu selection unexpectedly shows up
I installed Ubuntu 24.04 on an old PC to be used as a server, configured OS encryption with LUKS and unlocking with dropbear, had SSH running, etc. Took out the graphics card to check that it's still working fine. Turned it on once everything worked. Second time, never managed to SSH into the running server. Same for all consecutive attempts, and only way to shut it down was to cut power. I reinstalled the gpu to find that the grub menu screen resurfaced and wanted me to press enter to go to Ubuntu. I checked that the grub file has the timeout set to 0. Also, the system is single boot so I never expected the grub screen to show up at all, especially since it worked without it many times right up until I removed the gpu, both on reboots and power off/on. When I rebooted with the gpu installed, the grub screen magically disappeared and system went straight to dropbear. But if I remove the gpu once more I'll never know it's happening again, essentially meaning I can't start my server without a connected keyboard (to press enter on the grub menu), and then only by blindly tapping the enter key. Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Confusing question. You talk about the GPU and suddenly at the end you say keyboard. Please edit and clarify the question.

Thanks for the input, but I don't see what's confusing. The connected keyboard is the only way to press enter for the grub menu.

If you poweroff the system without a clean shutdown the grub menu will appear at the next boot.

Wait, what if the server loses power unexpectedly? Then I won't be able to restart it without an attached keyboard. Is there a way to disable this behavior?

You may want to remove all the stuff about the GPU it has noting to do with the question. The real question should have been  Why do I need to have a keyboard connected to my server all the time. Then it would match the answer.

I don't mind, but it essentially stops being a question when so heavily edited. Basically all that's really needed is the answer since it accurately describes the problem. Should I edit to say: "how to remove grub selection menu after power loss with no keyboard attached"? Not being sarcastic, genuinely inquiring.

Found the problem and answer.
Problem:
After a failure to shutdown cleanly, and then only if a keyboard is not connected, the grub selection menu will appear and stay indefinitely until a keyboard is connected and an enter key is pressed (once, the mere act of plugging in a keyboard caused the grub menu to disappear and system to continue booting, but other times I had to press enter).
Solution:
Edit the grub frontend configuration file:
sudo nano /etc/default/grub

Add the following line:
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0

Save the file, and update grub:
sudo update-grub

Afterwards, even after power loss with no keyboard connected, I found that the grub menu no longer appears and system boots up normally.
